# Developing Custom MLP for Mnist

Tags: deep-learning, mlp, mnist

I am trying to develop a custom MLP for MNIST Dataset with 2 hidden fully connected layers
Mnist: 28*28*1
FC1: input 28*28, output 512
FC2: input 512, output 128
Classifier: FC: input 128, output 10

I am adding batch normalization,relu,BN and dropout layer
Code:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(512, activation = "relu", input_shape = (input_dim,), kernel_initializer = RandomNormal(mean = 0.0, stddev = 0.039, seed = None)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0,5))

model.add(Dense(128, activation = "relu", input_shape = (input_dim,), kernel_initializer = RandomNormal(mean = 0.0, stddev = 0.039, seed = None)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(10, activation = "relu", input_shape = (input_dim,), kernel_initializer = RandomNormal(mean = 0.0, stddev = 0.039, seed = None)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(output_dim, activation = "softmax"))

model.summary()
```

Is something wrong by which I am defining the dense layers?